# How to handle new tab on IE selenium?

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, handle

When I open new tab on IE, I can't handle this. 
How to handle new IE tab and navigate to the url?

I use Ctrl+T

Comment: Hi @MosheSlavin Thanks for your helps. But I need to handle New IE tab browser to find elements. Ít's work with Chrome, But IE isn't.

Comment: You should explain more in your question... what have you tried?

Comment: My script
WebUI.openBrowser('google.com')
WebDriver driverInstance = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
//driverInstance.findElements(By.cssSelector('input[name="btnK"]')).get(0).sendKeys(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL,KeyEvent.VK_T)
WebUI.sendKeys(null, Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"t"))
driverInstance.switchTo().defaultContent()
driverInstance.get("google.com")
It's not work with IE browser.

Comment: Looks like you are opening a new tab here.  IE will block this by default.  (It decides that this is a popup and will prompt the user to accept...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
driver.switchTo().window()
```

Using `JavaScriptExecutor` is generally not recommended.

You should have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200473/selenium-ieserverdriver-not-finding-new-windows-for-ie9) and try Turning on Compatibility Mode.

Also, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48220024/8179099) for general info on using Selenium with IE.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The links were helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help, But It's not handle with IE browser,

Comment: @TrungNghĩaCao have you looked at the links In the answer?

Comment: Thanks, I found solutions from your answer

Comment: @TrungNghĩaCao glad to hear!

Comment: @MosheSlavin this is the answer for my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46251494/best-way-to-keep-track-and-iterate-through-tabs-and-windows-using-windowhandles/46346324#46346324

Answer (score 0):

Try with JavaScript executor,

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driverInstance;
js.executeScript("window.open(arguments[0], 'blank')", null):
```

Comment: This should work too... yet using JavaScript executor is generally not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for your helps, but it's not working with IE,

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer line of code may help to switch tabs.

```
//Switching between tabs using CTRL + tab keys.
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"\t");
//Switch to current selected tab's content.
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

for more information you can refer links below.

(1) [How To Open Tab And Switching Between Tabs In Selenium WebDriver](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/02/how-to-open-tab-and-switching-between.html)

(2) [Selenium 101: Managing Multiple Tabs](https://crossbrowsertesting.com/blog/test-automation/how-to-handle-multiple-tabs-in-selenium-webdriver/)

Comment: WebUI.openBrowser('google.com')
WebDriver driverInstance = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
//driverInstance.findElements(By.cssSelector('input[name="btnK"]')).get(0).sendKeys(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL,KeyEvent.VK_T)
WebUI.sendKeys(null, Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"t"))
driverInstance.switchTo().defaultContent()
driverInstance.get("google.com")

Comment: First I suggest you to make a test using new sample code and just try to switch the tabs from it. Once it work than try to implement in your original code. I also noticed that your code is not using '\t'. It is missing '\'.